# Syntax for filtering out array of values

Tags: vba

I am having issues with the syntax of the autofilter function. 
I know that the following filters for these values in an array:

```
wsDB.Range("A10:J10").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("T8932", "TR8434", …………)
```

What would the syntax be to filter out these values in an array?

Comment: Have you tried to use the macro record function? It might give you an idea of how it works.

Comment: I have. The problem is that the record function only displays code that determines which values to accept. Unfortunately, I need the opposite

Comment: oh ok, try this `Criteria1:="<>T8932", Criteria2:="<>TR8434", Operator:=xlAnd`

Comment: Thanks for the input!. The issue is that I actually have more than 15 different values I need to filter out. I was hoping to have it in an array to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Store “unwanted” filtered dara in a helper Range object, unfilter and show all your data, hide helper range, finally set it to visible data

```
Dim myRng As Range
With wsDB 
    With Range("J10", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        . AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("T8932", "TR8434", …………)
        Set myRng = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1). SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        myRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Set myRng = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1). SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With 
End With
```